# Using a private method inside another private method is bad?

Tags: oop, methods, private

I have searched for sources which touches this question, but unfortunately, I found nothing.

Normally we use private methods to carry out a closed operation which is specific only to that class. In that sense a second degree private method will be one who is serving for methods which are using that.

So it over complex to have such a lower down structure? What will be the result of further indentation? Do we need to extract that type of second degree private methods and put them into another class?

I will appreciate if anyone can give an answer with covering all the background aspects. :))

Comment: This might get closed for being opinion based. In my opinion no it's not complex and it's perfectly valid to have private methods call other private methods in the same class.

Comment: Any realistically complex program will have privates calling privates. Not sure why it is even a question.

Comment: @John3136 what if it has pretty much lower down methods? too many calls are there right? and what about the number of methods inside a class. Normally we prefer small classes right? :)) what about the test-ability?